# How to send Firebase custom token back to client side?

Tags: php, flutter

I'm having trouble trying to send my custom token from my server to my client side, on the server side it shows that I have a custom token but on my client side I keep on getting this error:

```
   I/flutter ( 6747): FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
```

This is how my code looks on the backend, I've basically already encoded my values into a jwt and stored into the `customToken`:

```
$customToken = $data . '.' . $encoded_signature;

  try {

    // Send the custom token back to the client as JSON
    $response = [
        'token' => $customToken,
    ];

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Handle errors and send an error response if needed
    http_response_code(500);
    $errorResponse = ['error' => 'Token creation failed'];
    echo json_encode($errorResponse);
}
```

this is my client code :

```
Future signInWithToken() async {
    try {
      final res = await http.get(Uri.parse(API.sendTokenInfo));

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        // Parse the JSON response to extract the token
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(res.body);
        final String token = data['token'];
        _auth.signInWithCustomToken(token);

        return token;
      } else {
        // Handle the error, e.g., display an error message
        print('Failed to fetch custom token: ${res.statusCode}');
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      throw Exception('something went wrong');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Debug it and check what `res.body` actually contains (before you try to decode it as JSON). I'd guess either it's blank, or doesn't contain JSON. Then debug the PHP code and see in detail what it's doing to produce that response. We can't run your code for you, so it's your job to investigate it more fully and pinpoint the issue. We can assist with potential solutions, once there's enough info to do so.

Comment: whats the best remedy i could follow , because the php code displays the response value when i print it , but the value is still not being sent to the client side ?

Comment: If PHP is echoing it, then it must be sent to the client. Maybe PHP is _not_ actually echoing it when it's being invoked by Flutter. Are there any PHP exceptions logged? Did you check what `res.body` actually contains? You haven't directly answered that question.

Comment: i performed a conditional check for res.body - and it it says the re.body is empty , but on the php code when i echo the value in question it does show that there is a value present

Comment: It's very strange then. Maybe add some logging to the php so you can see what it is (or isn't) doing when calling it via flutter ( as opposed to via a browser, or however you are testing it)